# Blank screen error on Unity 5

Tags: unity, wine, playonlinux

I installed Unity 5 using PlayOnLinux and wine 1.7.42 and everything went well. But when I open the editor I just got a blank screen. If I click to create a new scene, nothing happens...
Picture related, the state of the screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4FXy.png